# Rancher behind a Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, rancher

I have Rancher running behind this reverse proxy https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy and I can start any containers and workloads I want. But because it hosts the containers on a managed network the reverse proxy cant get the IP address of the container and wont forward to the application. I still learning how to use Rancher but from the docs there were a couple of labels that I thought would be useful but never got to try them because it doesnt allow me to add labels on the workload. Im using rancher 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can add labels and annotations on a workload through the Rancher UI under 'Show Advanced Options', but depending on what you are doing you might want to use the Ingress Controller that rancher can deploy for you to route traffic through services.  You dont want to have to route traffic to workloads directly by cluster IP.

https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/k8s-in-rancher/load-balancers-and-ingress/ingress/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/